# Continuous HRM with notification

Tags: heart-rate-monitor

I'm overwhelmed by the number of choices currently available and was hoping that someone here could help me out. I am looking for a wearable heart-rate and fitness monitor that fits the following:

- wrist or ankle band, i.e. not a chest-strap
- heart-rate monitoring is continuous, i.e. not just when I push a button
- I can set a heart-rate goal and be notified, either via vibration of the device or smartphone app

Bonus features which would be nice:

- sleep monitoring

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a Fitbit.

For more information on the specific product offerings (for trackers with a heart rate monitor): https://www.fitbit.com/uk/purepulse

I have had a fitbit before and I would wear one again. The app is very aesthetically pleasing and easy to use. Only downside is that you might be slightly off with your heart rate monitoring compared to a chest strap.